# Replace Backgroundworkerclass with worker thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have used Backgroundworkerclass to update my user interface element (Label). Please! Check my code below. It is working fine. But I am trying to replace Backgroundworkerclass and use simple worker thread to achieve the same goal. How can I achieve that? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

```
public void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        else
            label1.Text = "Busy Processing";
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint: start writing the code, THEN ask when something goes wrong.

Comment: If the `BackgroundWorker` is working fine, why would you want to complicate your life with a naked thread?

Comment: I am just learning to use both background thread and worker thread to solve the same issue. It is just for learning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delegate void DelegateDoWork(int number);
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(DoWork).Start();
    }

    public void ProgressBar(int i)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new DelegateDoWork(ProgressBar);
            this.Invoke(d, i);

        }
        else
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            ProgressBar(i);
        }
    }
```